# Ordering dataframe rows based on matching values in parallel columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

EDIT: As requested here are what the two dataframes look like before I concat them, and as they have the same column types so its literally:

```
# The Larger dataset, there are 4 other columns after, which the smaller dataframe shares in type

      id      Port  
    123ABC  Boston Port

# The smaller dataset

      id      Port  
    456DEF  Boston Port
```

I have a dataframe which is comparing two different datasets that have been merged into the same dataframe. An important note is that the two dataframes are of same number of columns but different number of rows, so one is 2979 rows and the other 791 rows.

The smaller dataset has matching NAME values in the larger one and I'm trying to get the rows to match based on the name. This is simple to do if the values are unique, its just using a dict map, however a caveat being something like this:

There are two `Boston Ports` however they have different ID numbers (since one port is located in Boston US, and there is one in the UK), the dict/map ignores this and places the first occurring one as match.

Example df:

```
  id      id2       Port1            Port2
123ABC   456DEF  Boston Port      Boston Port
789GHI   101JKL  Boston Port      Bridport Harbour
```

The second dataset (smaller one) was created based off of matching names inside a larger database, however the names arent unique, but other attributes are which I used to differentiate between them later on down in my code workflow.

The basic task here is to make sure any values in `Port1` and `Port2` align into the same row, and any duplicates get attached matched to `Port1` so a desired output ideally looks something like this:

```
  id      id2       Port1            Port2
123ABC   456DEF  Boston Port      Boston Port
789GHI   456DEF  Boston Port      Boston Port
```

This is the code snippet I'm using to map the two columns onto the same dataframe:

```
all_ents = pd.concat([big_dataset, small_dataset], axis=1)  # Concat the two dataframes 

big_name_mapper = dict(zip(big_dataset.id1, big_dataset.name))  # Create Mapping dictionary from larger dataframe
small_name_mapper = dict(zip(small_dataset.id2, small_dataset.name))  # Create Mapping dictionary from smaller dataframe

all_ents['Port1'] = all_ents.id1.map(big_name_mapper)  # Create New column based on big_name_mapper
all_ents['Port2'] = all_ents.id2.map(small_name_mapper)  # Create New column based on small_name_mapper
```

Anyone have any experience handling this? Thanks!

EDIT2: Final code,

Thanks @Dave!

This is the final code I used based on his answer with some filtering too since I don't want rows that dont match in this case.

```
Really_Big = BIG.merge(SMALL, how="outer", on="port", suffixes=(1, 2))

Really_Big = Really_Big[Really_Big['id1'].notnull()]
Really_Big = Really_Big[Really_Big['id2'].notnull()]  # Theres absolutely a much more efficient way to do this filter but for times sake this'll work.
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you give example of what the first and second dataframes look like and what the output you want looks like.

Comment: @adrtam fixed, and I state right above the code snippet what the ideal output would look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a lot like you want to join big and small datasets.
Suppose you have small:

```
       id         Port
0  456DEF  Boston Port
```

and big:

```
       id              Port
0  123ABC       Boston Port
1  789GHI       Boston Port
2  101JKL  Bridport Harbour
```

Merging them on `Port` will give you every pair of `id`s from small and big that share a `Port`:

```py
big_dataset.merge(small_dataset, how="outer", on="Port", suffixes=(1, 2))
```

If the port appears in only one dataset, it will show up once in the output.

```
      id1              Port     id2
0  123ABC       Boston Port  456DEF
1  789GHI       Boston Port  456DEF
2  101JKL  Bridport Harbour     NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think in SQL first. You have dataframes df1 and df2, both with columns Port and id, and you are asking if any id is different while Port is the same. So you are doing this

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.id, B.id, A.Port
FROM df1 A INNER JOIN df2 B ON A.Port=B.Port
WHERE A.id != B.id
```

In pandas dataframe, you just convert the above SQL into pandas code:

```
output = (
    df1.rename(columns={'id':'id1'})[['id1', 'Port']]
    .merge(df2.rename(columns={'id':'id2'})[['id2', 'Port']],
           on='Port',
           how='inner')
    .pipe(lambda df: df[df['id1'] 1= df['id2']])
    .drop_duplicates()
)
```

Then the dataframe `output` will contain three columns, `id1`, `id2`, `Port` showing all port with different ids.

Comment: I'm getting some unsolved references to the the existing dataframes (`df1`,`df2`), does `output` already exist as part of the concatenation, or is it being redefined?